# The ExposedDropdownMenu menu items dissapers when settext is used to define initial value in the XML or code

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, exposeddropdownmenu

I have this simple layout for ExposedDropdownMenu

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField3"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:hint="Gender">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/genderText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:simpleItems="@array/customer_gender"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="female"
        />

 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

If I don't set `android:text="female"` I can select items from `customer_gender`. However, I want to fill the form with Data Binding. It was simple setup.

Now, even if I'm using `binding.genderText.setText("a gender")`, I'm getting the same result. The list doesn't show the other elements.

If we enable editing on the menu then after erasing the set initial value, we can see the menu items. It seems like the setting the `text` overrides the menu list.

- How can I set the initial value?

Note: If I've used `binding.genderText.setText("female", false)` then everything works fine. Still, I cannot set in the XML as intended. I guess the `false` option is not available in the XML.